# Why List<T> Labels variable declaration does not work?

Tags: c#, list, generics

in my Class variables when I declare either of the following the compiler  complains about T.
I have included the Generics namespace as well

```
 class xyz
 {

    List<T> Labels = null; 

    List<T> Labels = new List<T>();

    public void abc (int a)
    {

    }

 }
```

Thanks for your help.

I do not know why someone voted down my question?  Not all of us are advanced C#, .NET programmers.  I did my research before putting the question here and David over here got my confusion and now I am gong to go  learn about generics.

Comment: Well what is `T` here? That would be fine in a generic class where `T` was a type parameter.

Comment: The compiler is actually expecting you to tell it what `T` is in the first place.

Comment: Did you mean `List<Label>` labels = `new List<Label>`? You need to tell it what `T` is

Comment: @Jon Skeet,  @ Frederic Hamidi : I guess from all these replies , I need to study the menaing of T in C#.  I consider myself a beginner in .NET,and C#. From all the replies that I got I still dont know:  1) How to define T . I thought T meant just accept any types here.  But apprently it does not mean that.  I dont know why someone gave me a -1 on this question either.

Comment: @user1298925: Basically you should read up on generics in C#. Any decent C# 2+ book should cover them.

Comment: If you really want a list of _any_ type, then use a `List<object>`. That means you have a list that might contain *both* integers and strings. But that's the same as using a non-generic list, and that's generally not what you want. @Charleh might have given you the answer already: `List<Label>`

Comment: thank you all for your comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how generics work.  You still have to supply it with an actual type.  This notation:

```
List<T>
```

basically means "a `List` of *something*."  You have to tell it what that something is.  For example, if it's a `List` of strings:

```
List<string>
```

or a `List` of some custom type:

```
List<MyCustomClass>
```

etc.

Generics are still as statically typed as anything else in C#, so the compiler needs to know the type.

Answer (score 2):

`T` is a placeholder for the datatype you want to make the list out of. See the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>();

    Console.WriteLine("\nCapacity: {0}", dinosaurs.Capacity);

    dinosaurs.Add("Tyrannosaurus");
    dinosaurs.Add("Amargasaurus");
    dinosaurs.Add("Mamenchisaurus");
    dinosaurs.Add("Deinonychus");
    dinosaurs.Add("Compsognathus");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    class xyz<T> //T is a type that needs to be made concrete somewhere, so if you need a generic class level field your class also needs to be generic
{

    List<T> Labels = null;

    List<T> Labels = new List<T>();

    public void abc(int a)
    {

    }

}
```

Of course, as ever, depends what you are *trying* to do!,  you may we  just want

```
List<string> Labels = new List<string>(); or similar.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a generic field for class xyz here. The class itself must be generic too so the compiler knows about T

```
class xyz<T>
{
    List<T> Labels = null;

    // more stuff
}
```